# Using the integral definition

Tags: integration, logarithms, proof-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Natural Logarithm and Integral Properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138871/natural-logarithm-and-integral-properties)

I was asked to prove that `ln(xy) = ln x + ln y`  using the integral definition.
While I'm not asking for any answers on the proof, I was wondering how to interpret and set-up this proof using the "integral definition" (As I am unsure what that means.)

**EDIT**

And to prove that `ln(x/y) = ln x - ln y`

Is it right to say this?

$$\ln(\frac{x}{y})=\int_1^{\frac{x}{y}} \frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}-\int_x^{\frac{x}{y}}\frac{dt}{t}.$$

Comment: [This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Definitions) might help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$\ln w=\int_1^w \frac{dt}{t}.$$
Thus
$$\ln(xy)=\int_1^{xy} \frac{dt}{t}=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}+\int_x^{xy}\frac{dt}{t}.$$
Now make an appropriate change of variable to conclude that the last  integral on the right is equal to $\ln y$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this also the same technique I would use to prove that `ln(x/y) = ln x - ln y`? I edited my question to ask if that's right.

Comment: @Johannes: No point in starting over. Note that $(x/y)(y)=x$. so by the above result $\ln(x)=\ln(x/y)+\ln(y)$. Basically finished!